# Substituting Words in a Body of Text with User Input via Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, regex, arrays, multidimensional-array, preg-replace

I have two sets of data stored in multidimensional arrays. One stores regular expressions which will be used to find whole words within a larger body of text:

```
Array
(
    [red] => Array
        (
            [0] => ~\b(a)\b~i
            [1] => ~\b(b)\b~i
            [2] => ~\b(c)\b~i
        )
    [orange] => Array
        (
            [0] => ~\b(d)\b~i
        )
    [green] => Array
        (
            [0] => ~\b(e)\b~i
        )
)
```

And the other contains what to replace those matches with:

```
Array
  (
    [red] => Array
        (
            [0] => <span class="red">A</span>
            [1] => <span class="red">B</span>
            [2] => <span class="red">C</span>
        )
    [orange] => Array
        (
            [0] => <span class="orange">D</span>
        )
    [green] => Array
        (
            [0] => <span class="green">E</span>
        )
)
```

For exemplary purposes, let's say the body of text is:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. a  The quick brown fox
>   jumps over the lazy dog. b  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy
>   dog. c  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. d  The quick
>   brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. e

The PHP function `preg_replace` doesn't handle multidimensional arrays, so how would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with your arrays, just use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($reg_cats as $key=>$reg_cat) {
    $yourstring = preg_replace($reg_cat, $rep_cats[$key], $yourstring);
}
```

`$reg_cats` is your array with regex, `$rep_cats` is your array with replacements. Since they have the same keys and the subarrays the same size, you can do that.

In the case you don't need to transform what you match (here you want to change the letter  to uppercase), you can use a single associative array:

```
$corr = array('<span class="red">$0</span>'    =>  '~\b(?:a|b|c)\b~i',
              '<span class="orange">$0</span>' =>  '~\bd\b~i',
              '<span class="green">$0</span>'  =>  '~\be\b~i');

$result = preg_replace($corr, array_keys($corr), $yourstring);
```

Comment: Why should I avoid multidimensional arrays? And what do you propose instead that will allow me to store categorized data in a similar way?

Comment: @daveycroqet: sorry, my second idea doesn't work cause you need to have the letters with uppercase.

Comment: I didn't realize foreach loops could deal with keys and elements in such a manner. Thank you for teaching me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to turn those into an array it can use.
something like this.

```
$r=array();$s=$r;$n=0;
foreach($Second_array_you_didn_t_name as $kk => $vv)
    foreach($vv as $k => $v)
    {
      $r[++$n]=$v;
      $s[$n]=$First_array_you_didn_t_name[$kk][$k]
    }
$tqbf="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. a The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. b The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. c The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. d The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. e";
print preg_replace($r,$s,$tqbf);
```

Comment: I'm still playing around with this and trying to figure it out. I will get back to you soon. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both arrays are similarly shaped, simply flatten both arrays like so:

```
$search = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $search);
$replace = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $replace);
```

Then perform the replacement:

```
preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```